# Reconstructing missing data

Tags: pandas, time-series, filtering, signal-processing, missing-data

I have the time series data whose values represent the time in milliseconds since the last received signal.

Something like that:

```
Time (ms)
750
758
755
738       
718
>2204
727
702
695
697
701
```

In my problem, I know that the value **2204** is three values accumulated by the sensor in just one. How can I automatize this task? What is the math behind this task? I thought in linear interpolation, but I don't know how to make only one value becomes three values.
I have more than 30 million rows, then everything is possible inside the series.
I am using pandas.

Thanks!

Comment: For the unsorted value, you can't

Comment: One point: as we can see, I need to interpolate a non-periodic time series data.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you data is smooth and does not change abruptly, you can use outlier detection to locate the accumulated values. Let `s` be your series, then:

```
times = np.round(s / s.shift())
s[times > 1]
# 5    2204
```

You can also estimate the number of repetitions:

```
times[times>1]
# 5    3.0
```